# Explanation of how probability density functions transform under the change of variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, intuition

I've just read about probability density function from this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).

In that article, there is some wired concept that I can't understand, please see the section named "Dependent variables and change of variables".

In that section, there is an equation appeared with short comment about it, "This follows from the fact that the probability contained in a differential area must be invariant under change of variables. That is, (and the equation appeared)"

I can't understand what that equation means and the sentence "the probability contained in a differential area must be invariant under change of variable", especially the "invariant under change of variable". Why the probability must be invariant under change of variable? and what is the change of variable?

Could anybody give me some insight to understand that equation?

Answer (score 3):

The wording is kind of throwing me off, but I think I get.

The probability of $x$ being in the infinitesimal area $dx$ is $f_X(x)dx$, because the first term $f_X$ is the probability density and the second term $dx$ is the surface of the infinitesimal area. If $g(x)$ maps values of the variable $x$ in $dx$ to values in the area $dy$, then the possibility of $y$ being in $dy$ would have to be equal to the possibility of $x$ being in $dx$. Hence

$$
f_Y(y)dy=f_X(x)dx
$$

Note that the probability is expressed as a product $f_X(x)dx$ only because $dx$ is considered "small enough" for the value of $f_X$ to be considered a constant. If the area was not infinitesimal, you would have to integrate $f_X(x)dx$ over it.

Comment: Please, no capital F for a PDF...

Comment: @Did It's been a while since I did probability so I mixed up the symbols. Thanks for pointing out so I could replace all instances!

Comment: Oh thanks a lot to your answer. However, I can't still get the point that why "fy(y)dy = fx(x)dx" must be satisfied. If we consider a change of variable x = g(y), then the function fx(x) becomes fy(y) = fx(g(y)), isn't it? please could you explain it more in detail? thank you.

Comment: I'll start with something simpler and build it up. Let's say you have a variable $x$ which can take positive integer values and $y=x^2$. What is the probability of y=4? It's exactly equal to the probability of x=2. Why? Because every value of $x$ is mapped to $x^2$ so $x=2$ and $y=4$ as outcomes of random experiments are one and the same.

In the same manner, for continuous variables, if for every $x\in dx$, $y=g(x) \in dy$, the outcome $x \in dx$ and the outcome $y \in dy$ is one and the same. Therefore,

$$
P(x \in dx)=f_x dx=f_y dy = P(y \in dy)
$$